# Symfony console: how to define option as string containing spaces

Tags: symfony, console

Is there any way to define option as string containing spaces, like this

```
$myscript.php test --comment="some string"
```

It outputs:

```
[RuntimeException]   
Too many arguments.

test [-c|--comment="..."]
```

However, it works if --comment doesn't contain spaces (for example: "some_string").

Comment: best thing I could come up with is to pass it as `test --comment=":some_string"` in this case when I find a option value which starts with  `:` I know that all `_` need to be replaced with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Maybe your `myscript.php` is passing the arguments the wrong way. Check this issue on github: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11205

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not about Symfony; it's about the command line. Just keep passing the quoted string.